# What is the best way to write this equation to have a better look?

Tags: equations

What is the best way to write the following equation:

```
\begin{flalign} 
\begin{aligned}
 &\qquad\qquad\frac{\partial^2 \ell}{\partial \bm{\phi}\partial\bm{\phi}'}=\\
 &\sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*} \Bigg(\bigg[\sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1} -\;\tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij} (1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'(1-\bm{P}_{ij})+\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij}}\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j + \tfrac{\bm{P}_{id_i}'(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})'(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})}{(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})'(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})+\bm{P}_{id_i}'\bm{P}_{id_i}}
 \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_{d_i} \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_{d_i}\bigg]\\
 &-\bigg[\sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1} \tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}
  \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \bm{P}_{ij}(1-\bm{P}_{ij}) \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j+\tfrac{(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})}{\bm{P}'_{id_i}}
  \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_{d_i} \bm{P}_{id_i}(1-\bm{P}_{id_i}) \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_{d_i} \bigg]\Bigg)\\
 &-\sum_{i=1}^{N^*} \sum_{j=2}^{n_i}\bigg[\tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij} (1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'(1-\bm{P}_{ij})+\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij}}\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j + \tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}
  \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \bm{P}_{ij}(1-\bm{P}_{ij}) \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j\bigg]
 \end{aligned}
 &&
 \end{flalign}
```

Following is an image to how it looks like in the way I wrote the code above

[image]

I tried also to use `multiline` but did not get a nice look either.

I change the code using `footnotesize`, the new code is

```
{\footnotesize
    \begin{flalign}  \label{18}
\begin{aligned}
 \frac{\partial^2 \ell}{\partial \bm{\phi}\partial\bm{\phi}'}&=\sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*} \Bigg(\bigg[\sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1} -\;\tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij} (1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'(1-\bm{P}_{ij})+\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij}}\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j + \tfrac{\bm{P}_{id_i}'(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})'(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})}{(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})'(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})+\bm{P}_{id_i}'\bm{P}_{id_i}}
 \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_{d_i} \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_{d_i}\bigg]\\
 &\qquad-\bigg[\sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1} \tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}
  \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \bm{P}_{ij}(1-\bm{P}_{ij}) \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j+\tfrac{(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})}{\bm{P}'_{id_i}}
  \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_{d_i} \bm{P}_{id_i}(1-\bm{P}_{id_i}) \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_{d_i} \bigg]\Bigg)\\
 &\qquad-\sum_{i=1}^{N^*} \sum_{j=2}^{n_i}\bigg[\tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij} (1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'(1-\bm{P}_{ij})+\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij}}\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j + \tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}
  \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \bm{P}_{ij}(1-\bm{P}_{ij}) \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j\bigg]
 \end{aligned}
 &&
 \end{flalign}
}
```

It looks now as: 
[image]

Comment: Please do not post code snippets - create minimal working examples (MWEs) instead.

Comment: I post it as it is because the equation is splitted in many line. I can't compile the above code here to show how it is very messy

Comment: Please state, in words, what you would like to achieve. Please also state what the main font size is and how wide the text block is.

Comment: @Mico This is a "Thesis" document with `12pt` font and `a4paper` paper size. This equation above is written in the appendix..

Comment: Do you use the default layout (with a very large outer margin) or do you customise your layout (say with `geometry`)?

Comment: In fact I add `{\footnotesize` -type the formula here- `}`, it is much better. I will reedit the above question with the new code.

Comment: The combination of  `\footnotesize` and `\tfrac` makes reading the material quite a chore -- unless a free magnifying glass is handed out...

Answer (score 6):

Do six lines. I changed the position of some of the brackets from before to after the summation sign and reduced the size.

Note that it should be `\bigl` for a left delimiter and `\bigr` for a right one (with the obvious variations for `Big`, `bigg` and `Bigg`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^2 \ell}{\partial \bm{\phi}\,\partial\bm{\phi}'}={}&
   \begin{aligned}[t]
   \sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*}
   \biggl(\,\sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1}\Bigl[
     & -\frac{\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij} (1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}
              {(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'(1-\bm{P}_{ij})+\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij}}
        \tilde{\mathbf{Y}}_j \tilde{\mathbf{Y}}'_j
     \\
     & +\frac{\bm{P}_{id_i}'(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})'(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})}
             {(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})'(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})+\bm{P}_{id_i}'\bm{P}_{id_i}}
       \tilde{\mathbf{Y}}_{d_i} \tilde{\mathbf{Y}}'_{d_i}\Bigr]
  \\
    -\sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1}\Bigl[
     & \frac{\bm{P}_{ij}}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}
       \tilde{\mathbf{Y}}_j \bm{P}_{ij}(1-\bm{P}_{ij}) \tilde{\mathbf{Y}}'_j
     \\
     &  +\frac{(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})}{\bm{P}'_{id_i}}
         \tilde{\mathbf{Y}}_{d_i} \bm{P}_{id_i}(1-\bm{P}_{id_i}) \tilde{\mathbf{Y}}'_{d_i} \Bigr]\biggr)
   \end{aligned}
\\
 &\begin{aligned}[t]
    -\sum_{i=1}^{N^*} \sum_{j=2}^{n_i}\Bigl[
    & \frac{\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij} (1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}
            {(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'(1-\bm{P}_{ij})+\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij}}
      \tilde{\mathbf{Y}}_j \tilde{\mathbf{Y}}'_j
    \\
    & + \frac{\bm{P}_{ij}}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}
        \tilde{\mathbf{Y}}_j \bm{P}_{ij}(1-\bm{P}_{ij}) \tilde{\mathbf{Y}}'_j\Bigr]
  \end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
&&
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I changed all `\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}` to `\tilde{\mathbf{Y}}` that's conceptually sounder. You may also want to use `\widetilde`, but I don't recommend so.

Comment: I'd be tempted to replace all instances of `\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}` with `\widetilde{\mathbf{Y}}`.

Comment: @Mico It should be `\tilde{\mathbf{Y}}`, much likely.

Comment: Nice touch to supply the missing inner brackets, by the way.

Comment: @egreg it is really looks very nice

Answer (score 3):

Reduce the text size or make it spread into several lines.

```
\begin{flalign}
{\footnotesize 
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^2 \ell}{\partial \bm{\phi}\partial\bm{\phi}'}=
&\sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*} \Bigg(\bigg[\sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1} -\;\tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij} (1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'(1-\bm{P}_{ij})+\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij}}\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j + \tfrac{\bm{P}_{id_i}'(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})'(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})}{(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})'(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})+\bm{P}_{id_i}'\bm{P}_{id_i}}\\&
\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_{d_i} \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_{d_i}\bigg]
-\bigg[\sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1} \tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}
\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \bm{P}_{ij}(1-\bm{P}_{ij}) \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j+\tfrac{(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})}{\bm{P}'_{id_i}}
\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_{d_i} \bm{P}_{id_i}(1-\bm{P}_{id_i}) \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_{d_i} \bigg]\Bigg)\\
&-\sum_{i=1}^{N^*} \sum_{j=2}^{n_i}\bigg[\tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij} (1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'(1-\bm{P}_{ij})+\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij}}\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j + \tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}
\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \bm{P}_{ij}(1-\bm{P}_{ij}) \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j\bigg]
\end{aligned}}
\end{flalign}
```

Comment: I just notice your answer, this is exactly what comes to my mind before I saw you answer

Comment: And you remembered to check the log before you posted this? Hint: `\footnotesize` is not allowed in math mode.

Comment: @daleif Yes it works in my system without any compilation error. If it is not working in your case, you can still use other options like `\tiny, \small`.

Comment: No error is not the same as not being correct. You get `LaTeX Font Warning: Command \footnotesize invalid in math mode` if you look in the log. Never use text font resizing commands in math mode.

Comment: @daleif  May be it goes with no correct because I use it outside `math mode`, I use it just before writing down the formula.

Comment: It is still a bad practise that should be avoided in a good document design.

Comment: Shrinking the font to make something fit is a bad idea regardless.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I've made the code a bit more legible and changed \Bigg( to \Biggl( etc.  Also, I'm using the multline environment from amsmath which is suitable here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\bP}{\bm{P}}
\newcommand{\tY}{\mathbf{\tilde Y}}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline} 
\frac{\partial^2 \ell}{\partial \bm{\phi}\partial\bm{\phi}'}=
 \sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*} \Biggl(\biggl[\sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1} -\;\frac{\bP_{ij}'\bP_{ij} (1-\bP_{ij})'}{(1-\bP_{ij})'(1-\bP_{ij})+\bP_{ij}'\bP_{ij}}\tY_j \tY'_j + \frac{\bP_{id_i}'(1-\bP_{id_i})'(1-\bP_{id_i})}{(1-\bP_{id_i})'(1-\bP_{id_i})+\bP_{id_i}'\bP_{id_i}}
 \tY_{d_i} \tY'_{d_i}\biggr]\\
 -\biggl[\sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1} \frac{\bP_{ij}}{(1-\bP_{ij})'}
  \tY_j \bP_{ij}(1-\bP_{ij}) \tY'_j+\frac{(1-\bP_{id_i})}{\bP'_{id_i}}
  \tY_{d_i} \bP_{id_i}(1-\bP_{id_i}) \tY'_{d_i} \biggr]\Biggr)\\
 -\sum_{i=1}^{N^*} \sum_{j=2}^{n_i}\biggl[\frac{\bP_{ij}'\bP_{ij} (1-\bP_{ij})'}{(1-\bP_{ij})'(1-\bP_{ij})+\bP_{ij}'\bP_{ij}}\tY_j \tY'_j + \frac{\bP_{ij}}{(1-\bP_{ij})'}
  \tY_j \bP_{ij}(1-\bP_{ij}) \tY'_j\biggr]
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose this, with package `geometry`. If you have the default layout with large margins, you can nest the equation contents in a `medsize` environment from `nccmath` (~ 80% of previous size):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{amsmath, bm, nccmath}
\usepackage{diffcoeff} 

 \begin{document}

 \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}\diffp[1,1]{\ell}{\bm{\phi},\bm{\phi}'} =
 \sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*} \Bigg( & \bigg[\begin{aligned}[t]\sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1} -\;\tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}'
\bm{P}_{ij} (1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'(1-\bm{P}_{ij})+\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij}}\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j + \tfrac{\bm{P}_{id_i}'(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})'(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})}{(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})'(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})+\bm{P}_{id_i}'\bm{P}_{id_i}}
 \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_{d_i} \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_{d_i} & \bigg]\\
 %&
 - \bigg[\sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1} \tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}
  \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \bm{P}_{ij}(1-\bm{P}_{ij}) \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j+\tfrac{(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})}{\bm{P}'_{id_i}}
  \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_{d_i} \bm{P}_{id_i}(1-\bm{P}_{id_i}) \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_{d_i} &\bigg]\Bigg)
  \end{aligned}\\
% &
-\sum_{i=1}^{N^*} \sum_{j=2}^{n_i} & \bigg[\tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij} (1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'(1-\bm{P}_{ij})+\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij}}\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j + \tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}
  \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \bm{P}_{ij}(1-\bm{P}_{ij}) \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j\bigg]
\end{aligned}
 \end{equation}
 \bigskip

 \begin{equation}
\begin{medsize}
\begin{aligned}\diffp[1,1]{\ell}{\bm{\phi},\bm{\phi}'} =
 \sum_{i=1}^{N-N^*} \Biggl( & \Biggl[\begin{aligned}[t]\sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1} -\;\tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}'
\bm{P}_{ij} (1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'(1-\bm{P}_{ij})+\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij}}\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j + \tfrac{\bm{P}_{id_i}'(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})'(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})}{(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})'(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})+\bm{P}_{id_i}'\bm{P}_{id_i}}
 \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_{d_i} \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_{d_i} & \Biggr]\\
 %&
 - \Biggl[\sum_{j=2}^{d_i-1} \tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}
  \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \bm{P}_{ij}(1-\bm{P}_{ij}) \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j+\tfrac{(1-\bm{P}_{id_i})}{\bm{P}'_{id_i}}
  \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_{d_i} \bm{P}_{id_i}(1-\bm{P}_{id_i}) \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_{d_i} &\Biggr]\Biggr)
  \end{aligned}\\
% &
-\sum_{i=1}^{N^*} \sum_{j=2}^{n_i} & \biggl[\tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij} (1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'(1-\bm{P}_{ij})+\bm{P}_{ij}'\bm{P}_{ij}}\mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j + \tfrac{\bm{P}_{ij}}{(1-\bm{P}_{ij})'}
  \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}_j \bm{P}_{ij}(1-\bm{P}_{ij}) \mathbf{\tilde{Y}}'_j\biggr]
\end{aligned}
\end{medsize}
 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```